# Giving feedback to Watson

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson, visual-recognition

I have a trained classifier for identifying if the image is of football or tennis. Is it possible to give a feedback to the existing positive examples rather than by adding a new class? Can the classifier be improved by adding  images to the zip file and updating the classifier or is there a better approach to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the question is here. What do you mean by "Is it possible to give a feedback to the existing positive examples rather than by adding a new class?". What do you mean by "feedback"? Examples have to be either positive or negative, nothing in between.

Comment: @EdShee I am using Watson to predict the tags, I am trying to give a feedback to the service if there is a user approving the tags from watson. So the result of the manual intervention can be used to improve the model. I know I can update the model to add more classes as a zip file. Is it possible to tweak it to accept a single file into a existing class?

Comment: Yes. If a user reinforces a class as being positive or negative you can add that to your initial training set (or change the value in your initial training set) and then retrain the classifier with your dataset again. What you can't do is ask the classifier just to change its results for one image. Each time you want to provide "feedback" it needs to train a whole new classifier so it's best to give it all the data you have at that point in time.